# IIS management rights for non admin users assigned by GPO

Tags: iis, active-directory, gpo

I have developers using IIS. There is a new policy in place where these users shouldn't have local admin rigts.
Is there a way how to give them IIS management permission based on their AD group memmbership ?

Comment: Is this any use? https://blogs.iis.net/krolson/delegate-application-creation-for-non-admininistrator-accounts

Comment: Not really as I have IIS deployed on targeted machines and currently developers are local admins so I can't redeploy IIS

Comment: Which version of IIS? Here are instructions for IIS 7: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/leesab/2014/07/30/delegating-iis-administration-to-domain-users-non-administrators/

Comment: I'm using version 7.5   There is a local group called IS_IUSRS where I've added a user and got access. So I'm trying to update this group by GPO for which I've created a group and added memmbers into it. The group has showen in my local IS_IUSRS but when I try to open IIS the same message appears

Comment: I've managed to push users to the group by a GPO but it doesn't provide access to IIS unless I add a user manualy to the group.